# Insert large data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I tested to load a small file into MongoDB collection. The code I have written using Mongo-Spark Connector. I have loaded and appended the JSON file in MongoDB and it was successful because the test file was smaller than 16 MB.
The JSON file is look like this:
[image]

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import com.mongodb.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.bson.Document
import org.bson.Document._
import org.bson._
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
import jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.annotations.Ignore

import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollection
//import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoConnection
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.mongodb.casbah.gridfs.Imports._

import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import com.mongodb.spark.config._
```

and the code snippet is:

```
val df = sparksessionobject.read.json("D:/split_json_part/part1_final/part-00000.json").toDF() //Small size file
val writeConfig = MongoSpark.save(df.write.mode("append"), WriteConfig(Map("collection" -> "play"), Some(WriteConfig(sparksessionobject))))
```

Here it is the `play` Collection view:
[image]

**But the problem has started here:** We have to use [Casbah API](https://github.com/mongodb/casbah) to load large size file in MongoDB database.
I have a 2.2 GB JSON and I have loaded into MongoDB.

```
val mongoColl = MongoConnection("192.168.70.13", 27017)
//val mongoClient = MongoClient("192.168.70.13", 27017)
val db = mongoColl("issuer")
val gridFS = GridFS(db)

val imageFile = new File("D:/split_json_part/part1_final/part-00000.json")
val fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(imageFile)

    val gfsFile=gridFS.createFile(fileInputStream)
    gfsFile.filename="part-00000.json"
    gfsFile.save()
```

The file got loaded inside the database but The problem is I am not getting the records properly in the Documents, Data is coming in binary form and also how can I append this chunks later? I have no idea.
here it is the view of 2.2 GB `fs.chunk`in the MongoDB database.
[image]

How to solve the issue?
I have taken the reference of this links:

1. https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/gridstore.html
2. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#when-to-use-gridfs
3. https://github.com/mongodb/casbah
4. https://blog.knoldus.com/using-gridfs-within-scala-to-store-large-files-in-mongodb/